Nav Menu (HTML/CSS) uses a "Mega Menu" as one of the dropdowns. Works great standard view but creates gap between buttons on smaller screens
I’ve been working on this site navigation menu for weeks, and I’m stuck. Everything works fine on full screen, but issues arise when I resize the browser to test responsiveness. Specifically, when the "directorate" button’s submenu appears, it pushes the other buttons down, creating a gap equal to the height of the mega menu that open upon hovering. This doesn’t happen with the other buttons, which have different classes/Styles. I suspect it’s related to the Mega Menu's columns or another property specific to the Mega menu I use on that button. I’ve tried all the resources I have; school notes, GPT, W3resources, experimenting with different combinations of "absolute" and "relative" positions, as well as display properties, but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read!





* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------- MAIN Navbar container ----------------------------------- */
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Clear floats */
.navbar::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* ----------------------- Home House-Icon (and its Link) Styles  ------------------------------ */

/* Home icon-Link styling */
.navbar__home-link {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Home icon styling */
.navbar__home-icon {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  fill: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}

/* Home icon hover styling */
.navbar__home-icon:hover {
  background-color: rgb(85, 83, 83);
}

/* ----------- Main Navigation Menu Buttons And Dropdown Menu Containers  ----------------- */

/* The dropdown menu container for the Mega menu (4 columns) - Used for "Directorate" button*/
.navbar__dropdown--mega {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* The dropdown menu container for the Regular menu (Single column) - Used for the all the other buttons (Not the "Directorate" button) */
.dropdown__normal {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

/* Styles for the dropdown trigger buttons that are on the navigation bar. they are applied when used inside .navbar__dropdown--mega or .dropdown-normal containers */
.navbar__dropdown--mega .dropbtn,
.dropdown__normal .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17.5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

/* Hover style for navbar buttons */
.navbar a:hover,  /* Hover style for navbar home Icon since its used as a link */
.navbar__dropdown--mega:hover .dropbtn, /* Hover style for "Directorate" button*/
.dropdown__normal:hover .dropbtn {       /* Hover style for the rest of the buttons on the nav bar*/
  background-color: rgb(85, 83, 83);
  color: white;
}

/* Links inside the normal dropdown */
.dropdown__content-normal a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.dropdown__content-normal a:hover {
  background-color: #9b0b0b;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown__content-mega,
.dropdown__content-normal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(119, 7, 7, 0.664);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the Mega dropdown menu on hover */
.navbar__dropdown--mega:hover .dropdown__content-mega{
  display: block;
}

/* Show the Normal dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown__normal:hover .dropdown__content-normal {
  display: block;
}

/* ----------- MEGA MENU: Styles for Mega Dropdown Menu, its Columns, and its Links ------------- */

.dropdown__content-mega {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}


/* Create columns for the mega menu */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%; /* Four equal columns */
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 550px;
  border-right: 3px solid #d3d0d054;
}

/* Style links inside the columns */
.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Style for the column headers */
.column-header {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

/* Add a background color on hover for links except headers */
.column a:not(.column-header):hover {
  background-color: #9b0b0b;
  color: white;
}

/* Header hover effect */
.column-header:hover {
  color: #9b0b0b;
}

/* Remove border from the last column */
.column:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* ----------------- SIMPLE MENU: Normal (single column) Dropdown Menu Styles -------------- */



/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown__normal .dropdown__content-normal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 230px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(119, 7, 7, 0.664);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* New class to float the "links" button to the right */

.dropdown-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* --------------------------------- Centered SOCSOUTH text -----------------------------------*/
.navbar__text {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 10%);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}


/* ------------- Responsive Design ********WHWRE I THINK THE ISSUE IS******* -------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  /* Remove SOCSOUTH text on smaller screens */
  .navbar__text {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar__home-icon {
    order: 1;
  }

  /* Align menu buttons horizontally under the home icon */
  .navbar__dropdown--mega,
  .dropdown__normal {
    order: 2;
    position:relative;
    float: none;
    display: inline-flex;
  }

  .navbar__dropdown--mega .dropbtn,
  .dropdown__normal .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  }

  /* Position dropdowns to open to the right on smaller screens only */
  .dropdown__content-mega {
    position: relative;
    left: 0; 
    width: auto;
  
  }

  .dropdown__content-normal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; /* Open to the right */
  }

  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-right: none;
  }

}
    <!----------------------------Home Icon and "SOUTH" Text---------------------------------------->
    
<body style="background-color:white;">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar__home-link navbar__home-icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <path d="M32 12l22 22h-8v18h-10V40H28v12H18V34h-8z"></path>
      </svg>
    </a>

    <div class="navbar__text">SOUTH</div>

    <!---------------------------DIRECTORATES DROP DOWN--------------------------------------> 
    
    <div class="navbar__dropdown--mega">
      <button class="dropbtn">Directorates</button>
      <div class="dropdown__content-mega">
        <div class="row">
        <!----------------------------------------- COLUMN 1 ----------------------------------> 
        
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Command Group</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Manpower and Personnel</a>
          </div>
          
          <!--------------------------------------- COLUMN 2 ----------------------------------> 
          
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Intelligence</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
             <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          
          <!--------------------------------------- COLUMN 3 ------------------------------------> 
          
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Operations</a>
            <a href="#">Current Ops</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Future Ops</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Training | Readiness | Exercise</a>
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Information Operations</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          
          <!------------------------------------------ COLUMN 4 --------------------------------------> 
          
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Logistics</a>
            <a href="#">Engineers</a>                
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Strategy | Plans | Policy</a>
            <a href="#" class="column-header">Communications</a>
            <a href="#">Field Technical Unit</a>
            <a href="#">Cybersecurity</a>
            <a href="#">Opes</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!---------------------------------SPECIAL STAFF DROP DOWN----------------------------------->       
    <div class="dropdown__normal">
      <button class="dropbtn">Special Staff</button>
      <div class="dropdown__content-normal">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!---------------------------------SUBORDINATE UNITS DROP DOWN--------------------------------> 
    
    <div class="dropdown__normal">
      <button class="dropbtn">Units</button>
      <div class="dropdown__content-normal">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  <!--------------------QUICK LINKS | SUPPORT DROP DOWN----------------------------------------->  
  
    <div class="dropdown__normal dropdown-right">
      <button class="dropbtn">Quick Links | Support</button>
      <div class="dropdown__content-normal">
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




The root of the issue is that the dropdown menu, that is absolute positioned on larger viewports, gets switched to relative below 768px viewport width. Since it is not taken out of the flow any more now, it pushes the following menu items further to the right. You need to keep this absolute positioned, if you want this to work properly.

Thank you for taking the time to review code. It was originally absolute, but the menu would not show at all. I used browsers inspect tool and it shows the highlighted menu when forcing the "hover" state, but nothing I've tried makes the actual menu appear when set to "absolute". I also changed the mega menus container to "relative" but still won't work. however, now that you pointed that out, I will continue troubleshooting the code with the position in "absolute" and see if I can find what's keeping it from showing up. if you think of any other pointers, please let me know. thanks!

The .navbar__dropdown--mega class sets overflow: hidden, so if you position the dropdown menu to the right of the menu item, you can't see it. Remove/ overwrite that, and then try position: absolute; left: 100%; on the dropdown menu.

Yes! that worked! thank you so much for taking the time to help! I have not messed around with HTML/CSS for years and this was driving me crazy. I'm new to here and couldn't figure out how to mark your answer (or upvote) as the one that worked in case anyone has this same problem in the future. let me know how I can upvote somehow if this also helps with ranking or what not. thanks again!
